# Inter-column padding in Bootstrap 4 without side margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1. I'd like to have a grid of cells (Box A-E) with some spacing in between them. If I set padding on each column, I also get padding on the left and right side that breaks alignment with other elements; I would like Box A and Box D to align with the left edge of Top Box, for example.

The documentation talks about using a negative margin to offset this but I couldn't figure out where to put it.

The set of boxes is dynamic (there could be dozens) and I'd like to apply consistent styling to all of them, rather than make modifications to specific boxes.

I also want to avoid making modifications to Top Box, which is a stand-in for many existing UI elements in my real page that cannot easily be changed.

[image: Not what I want]

Here's a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u5094cjb/2/

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="container">

  <!-- ideally don't change this part --> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="box">Top Box</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- change this part only -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box A</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box B</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box C</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box D</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box E</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to accomplish it seems like you're using a bit "too much" code. I cleaned it up a bit so now that you only have two rows and added `px-1` to your first `col`

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col px-1">
            <div class="box">Top Box</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box D</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 px-1">
            <div class="box">Box E</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly how I'd like it to look, though in my application there are many other components I would have to modify to get everything lined up, so I was hoping it was possible only by modifying the area with Box A-E.

Comment: By your "application" do you mean just having more rows with col-4's? I think this should work with everything since they all have the same `px-1` gutter spacing and each row is nested in a `container`. Feel free to update the question if you'd like.

Comment: In reality I have a whole web app with a lot of UI elements, and I'm trying to slip in this box grid *ideally* without having to update lots of other `<div>`s throughout the app. So ideally I would limit my changes to just the Box A-E part. I updated the question. Sorry if it wasn't or still is not clear.

Comment: @rgov sorry for the delay -- just finished a sprint. I think I get you now. You just want to get this result but without changing the top part. So then what I would do is remove all the gutter spacing (`px-1`) from all of the `col-4`'s and you should be good to go!

Comment: Yeah you are right. That makes the effect I want though the spacing between boxes is quite large. I guess the default padding for a `<col>` is 15px so the inter-column distance is 30px.

Comment: Ok I think this is doing what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/Lawdr385/1/ though without using Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Ahh. Negative mergin classes like `mx-n4` were added in Bootstrap 4.2. That's why the sample in the docs wasn't working.

Comment: @rgov interesting - did that work for you? Or do you want a solution in Bootstrap?

Comment: Here it is with Bootstrap 4.6. Thanks for pointing out it was easier than I thought. https://jsfiddle.net/Lawdr385/2/ I'll try to simplify the HTML to avoid unnecessary nesting.

Comment: @rgov Great! Honestly, I just guessed what version of Bootstrap you were using because It wasn't in the question and just threw in that CDN. But you're right, with 4.6 and after you can use `mx-n1` on `row` which seemed to do the trick for you! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bootstrap classes `pr-1` & `pl-0` instead of `px-1` to Box A and Box D

For example,

```html
<div class="col-4 px-1">
  <div class="box">Box B</div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 px-1">
  <div class="box">Box C</div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 pr-1 pl-0">
  <div class="box">Box D</div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 px-1">
  <div class="box">Box E</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kongallis/cebqw7y8/2/

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to apply the same styling to all of them, rather than modify specific boxes. In the real version the number of boxes is dynamic and there could be dozens, so having to know which ones to apply `pr-1 pl-0` to would be complex.